# Any advide on transfering iphone contacts to itunes?

Tags: iphone

So here's the thing, I accidently spilled water on my iphone 4, although it has been fixed, it still get kind of "unstable", sometimes it just suddenly shut itself down.
Now I'm saving money for the new iphone 5, but I have a pile of important contacts saved on my watered iphone 4 and I'm so afraid that they'll be gone with the damaged phone right before I could get a new one. But if I can copy these contacts to itunes, then next time I'll be able to transfer them to the new iphone,right? Or just copy to computer? Any difference?
Anyway, I just want the contacts to be backuped, any good idea? I don't mind if I have to pay for something but it would be the best if there's a free and easy way.Help me please.

Comment: Have you not heard of iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mention what computer you have: a Mac or a Windows machine.

Anyway, for a Mac it's like this...

I had the same problem a few months ago. With iCloud you can have all the contacts in sync on all your devices.

1. If you are using contacts from iCloud, you are good to go, you have nothing to do. :)
2. If not, let's say you never had any contacts in iCloud, like I had...

   a. You first need to sync your contracts with your Mac, via iTunes.

   [image]

   b. Then export the local contacts from the Contacts app.

   *. Activate iCloud contacts from System Preferences > iCloud, if you haven't done that already.

   c. Then import the file created on step b. in your iCloud, from the Contacts applications.

   d. When you get the new phone, all you have to do is set up iCloud and you'll have all the contacts.

---

If you don't what to use iCloud, you can just sync your contacts locally and then restore your backup into your new iPhone, when you get it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using Google Contact http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2753077&topic=21369&ctx=topic

Comment: Could you please summarize on how the OP could use google contact, thank you ?